# Powershell + Zabbix API

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I get error 32500 - No permissions to referred object or it does not exist.
I know that something wrong with groups.
Connection:

```
if(!$credential){
    $credential = Get-Credential
}
$baseurl = 'http://zabbix'
$params = @{
    body =  @{
        "jsonrpc"= "2.0"
        "method"= "user.login"
        "params"= @{
            "user"= $credential.UserName
            "password"= $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
        }
        "id"= 1
        "auth"= $null
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    uri = "$baseurl/api_jsonrpc.php"
    headers = @{"Content-Type" = "application/json"}
    method = "Post"
}
$result = Invoke-WebRequest @params
```

host create:

```
$params.body = @{
    jsonrpc= "2.0"
    method= "host.create"
    params= @{
        host = "host";
        interfaces = @{type = 1;main=1;useip=1;ip="10.10.0.0";dns= "";port="10050"};
        groups =@{groupid="197"}

        #"templates"=@{"templateid"="14415"};

    }
    auth = ($result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).result
    id = 2
} | ConvertTo-Json

$result = Invoke-WebRequest @params
$result = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$result | fl
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: i remarked if groupid is 1 it is work. When it has double-digit it wont

Comment: Could you please post that as an answer and after a while mark it as accepted :)

Comment: That's really, really not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your final JSON should doublequote the group ID. The way you generate the JSON apparently does not do that.

Comment: I tried groups = @{"groupid"="197"} but it doesn't. When I use 1 digit id it works...

Comment: Try debugging it and printing out the raw JSON sent. How does the group ID look there?

Comment: something like this:  \"groups\":  {\r\n           
                       \"groupid\":  \"197\"\r\n                              }

Comment: Does a group with that ID exist? If you are not attempting to do this with a superadmin account, could you please try that as a test?

Comment: Yes, that id exists. It works for all id's till 9. If it is 10 or higher no. Account is superadmin.

Comment: I still suspect quoting not being right - but which Zabbix version is it? Can you try sending raw JSON with curl?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$groups = @()
$groups += @{"groupid"="64"}
$groups += @{"groupid"="5"}

$params.body = 
@{
    "jsonrpc" = "2.0"
    "method" = "host.create"
    "params" = @{
        "host" = "Linux server"
        "interfaces" = @{
                "type"= 1
                "main"= 1
                "useip"= 1
                "ip"= "192.168.3.1"
                "dns"= ""
                "port"= "10050"
            }
        "groups" =  $groups
        }
     "auth" = $Tocken
     "id" = 1} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20
```